# how to do operations based grouped values and single value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was given the data below and was asked to calculate the actual price column which depends on column S as well as two grouped values in column T and column V based on column R. The calculation logic is quite easy but there is a lot of data rows. I can't figure out how to do this in excel in a systemic way. Doing this manually could be cumbersome due to the large amount of data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to get unmerged source data.

My second: use helper columns.

Assumption: merging is based on the name column.

You get the unmerged values with the formulas:

- projectTotal unmerged: `=INDEX($T$2:$T$8,MATCH(R2,$R$2:$R$8,0))`
- actualTotal unmerged: `=INDEX($V$2:$V$8,MATCH(R2,$R$2:$R$8,0))`

INDEX returns the first value of each group.

You can either use these formulas within your formula or you really build those helper columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have ***tried***, may be there is more eloquent way to resolve this query,  but here is as is,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula in cell `U2`

```
=ROUND((LOOKUP(2,1/(($V$2:V2<>"")*($R$2:R2=R2)),$V$2:V2)/
LOOKUP(2,1/(($T$2:T2<>"")*($R$2:R2=R2)),$T$2:T2))*S2,2)
```

- `LOOKUP()` Function will `Auto-CSE` this formula for you,
- This formula works because the top left cell of a merged range holds its value,
- Lastly, try to avoid merged cells they are Excel's worst nightmare.

Comment: Thanks. It seems working but I need to figure out how it works.

Comment: @stt106 the `LOOKUP()` Function performs an approximate match lookup in a one-column or one-row range, and returns the corresponding value from another one-column or one-row range. LOOKUP's default behavior makes it useful for solving certain problems in Excel. Have you tried to evaluate the formula, you will be able to understand more clearly how it works,